# With open's IF statement

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have created this bit of code, which works perfectly in what I want it to do:

```
name = list()

with open("Classes\Class " + cl + ".txt", "r+") as f:
    for line in f:
        if ("%s %s" %(fn, ln)) in line:
            name.append(line.strip() + " %s" %(s))
            with open("Classes\NewFile.txt", "a") as g:
                for line in f:
                    if line != name:
                        g.write("\n" + line.strip())
```

Now I want to add an else statement so if `fn` and `ln` is not in the file it will write to the file instead of doing all the other stuff. I added the else statement but now the if statement only checks the first line in the file then moves to the else statement.

```
with open("Classes\Class " + cl + ".txt", "r+") as f:
for line in f:
    if ("%s %s" %(fn, ln)) in line:
        name.append(line.strip() + " %s" %(s))
        with open("Classes\NewFile.txt", "a") as g:
            for line in f:
                if line != name:
                    g.write("\n" + line.strip())
    else:
        f.write("\n" + da)
```

How do I stop this?

Comment: Your description of the output is confusing, can you post output from before and after you add the else?

Comment: You write to same file you read from with `f.write()`. Maybe you want to write to `g`?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan, without the else statement, it will read all lines in the document searching for fn and ln. With the else statement it will only read the first line in the document then move onto the else statement. Does that help? I find it hard to explain my own code

Comment: How did you know that it only read the first line? Did you tried to print `line` while iterating?

Comment: @skyline75489 the document being read has two lines in it, first line has 'Harr Rive 10' and the second has 'Bob Bobbington 10'. If I make fn Harr and ln Rive and include the else statement in the code it will create the new file ect.. However if I make fn Bob and ln Bobbington and include the else statement in the code it runs the else statement. This is how I know it reads the first line only.

Comment: How about fixing the indentation of your code so that we can be certain about it?

Comment: I'm 99% sure this is an indentation problem. Since the indentation is broken on both bits of sample code, there's no reason to believe that his `else` statement is actually applying to the `if` instead of the `for` or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

So I try to make a simple example out of your code:

```
fn = 'Harr'
ln = 'Rive'

# fn = 'Bob'
# ln = 'Bobbington'

with open('1.txt', 'r+') as f:
    for line in f:
        if ("%s %s" %(fn, ln)) in line:
            print('Wow')

        else:
            print('Nah')
```

My file is simply this:

```
Harr Rive 10
Bob Bobbington 10
```

The output is:

```
Wow
Nah
Nah
```

The last one is because of the newline at the end of file

If uncommented, the output is:

```
Wow
Nah
Nah
```

So I'm guessing you are missing something there. Or it actually didn't "skip" anything like you said.

Comment: Should else not have the same amount of indents as if? Also if the first is true it shouldn't run the second, right?

Comment: Your `else` statement applies to the `for` loop, not the `if`. It will always execute provided that the for loop terminates naturally, which it will.

Comment: My bad. I made some edit. But the code still works as expected.

Comment: I am beginning to become coonfused, it appears to be that if statements do not work inside of with open function?

Comment: That's not possible. You can try to print the `line` at the beginning of `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing unusual with the processing of an `if` statement within a `with`.

Your input file is:

```
Harr Rive 10
Bob Bobbington 10
```

Your code (with corrected indentation) is:

```
name = list()

with open("Classes\Class " + cl + ".txt", "r+") as f:
    for line in f:
        if ("%s %s" %(fn, ln)) in line:
            name.append(line.strip() + " %s" %(s))
            with open("Classes\NewFile.txt", "a") as g:
                for line in f:
                    if line !=name:
                        g.write("\n" + line.strip())
        else:
            f.write("\n" + da)
```

In the first case with `fn = 'Harr'` and `ln = 'Rive'`, the first `if` statement will be true. A decorated version of the line is then appended to the end of *list* `name` and the code will then open file `Classes\NewFile.txt` and append to it the rest of the lines in the input file. Note that *all* remaining lines from the input file will be appended to the output file because the condition `line != name` will always be true - *a string will never equal a list*. The `else` will never execute.

In the second case with `fn = 'Bob'` and `ln = 'Bobbington'`, the first `if` will fail because the first line of input is `Harr Rive 10` which does not contain `Bob Bobbington`. Hence the `else` block is executed. Then the second input line is read (`Bob Bobbington 10`) and this does match the outer `if` condition and the inner loop is entered. But the last line of the file has been consumed so the inner `for` loop is not entered and the code terminates.

So everything works according to your code, and as you can see, there are no peculiarities concerning `if` nested in `with` as you suppose.

Comment: So I would change !=name to !=("%s" %(name))? Sorry for late replys

Comment: @Harrrive2112: it's hard to say what you should do since you don't say what you want to do.